# Convert D3 quicksort example to D3 version 6 in React

Tags: javascript, d3.js, quicksort

I'm trying to convert the D3 example implementation of Quicksort from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e1e1e7e2c360bec054ba which is in a prior version to version 6 (currently the latest).

I have been able to get the animation to resolve to the end state but the swapping animation appears differently from the one on the web page.

This is what I have done so far (which may not be of any use), I am currently hoping to understand how to convert the D3 Quicksort example to the latest version?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-quicksort-example-k6xv7?file=/src/Sort.js

Example without React:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.line {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.line--pivot {
  stroke: #f00;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

.line--inactive {
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script>

var n = 200,
    array = d3.shuffle(d3.range(n)),
    actions = quicksort(array.slice()).reverse();

var margin = {top: 230, right: 40, bottom: 230, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scalePoint().domain(d3.range(n)).range([0, width]);
var a = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, n - 1])
        .range([-45, 45]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var line = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "line")
  .selectAll("line")
    .data(array)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("transform", transform)
    .attr("y2", -height);

var transition = d3.transition()
    .duration(150)
    .on("start", function start() {
      var action = actions.pop();
      switch (action.type) {
        case "swap": {
          var i = action[0],
              j = action[1],
              li = line._groups[0][i],
              lj = line._groups[0][j];
          line._groups[0][i] = lj;
          line._groups[0][j] = li;
          transition.each(function() { line.transition().attr("transform", transform); });
          break;
        }
        case "partition": {
          line.attr("class", function(d, i) {
            return i === action.pivot ? "line--pivot"
                : action.left <= i && i < action.right ? null
                : "line--inactive";
          });
          break;
        }
      }
      if (actions.length) transition = transition.transition().on("start", start);
      else transition.on("end", function() { line.attr("class", null); });
    });

function transform(d, i) {
  return "translate(" + x(i) + "," + height + ")rotate(" + a(d) + ")";
}

function quicksort(array) {
  var actions = [];

  function partition(left, right, pivot) {
    var v = array[pivot];
    swap(pivot, --right);
    for (var i = left; i < right; ++i) if (array[i] <= v) swap(i, left++);
    swap(left, right);
    return left;
  }

  function swap(i, j) {
    if (i === j) return;
    var t = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = t;
    actions.push({type: "swap", "0": i, "1": j});
  }

  function recurse(left, right) {
    if (left < right - 1) {
      var pivot = (left + right) >> 1;
      actions.push({type: "partition", "left": left, "pivot": pivot, "right": right});
      pivot = partition(left, right, pivot);
      recurse(left, pivot);
      recurse(pivot + 1, right);
    }
  }

  recurse(0, array.length);
  return actions;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please make your code runnable using a stack snippet, so we don't have to guess about what you see.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried putting it in a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-quicksort-example-k6xv7?file=/src/Sort.js which I think is showing the unexpected behaviour of all elements being animated at once and then accelerating to the final state.

Comment: Have you tried turning your code into a [mre]? Remove ReactJS and see if the problem persists

Comment: Thank you, I think I've added a snippet with vanilla javascript and left the react version in codesandbox, the animation vanilla javascript appears to be similar to the one on the D3 page. Do you know what might be causing the difference in the React version?

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to an answer, by changing the  .style('transform', transform) properties on the line element, the results are becoming similar in React as in the vanilla javascript version. Thank you!

Comment: Great! So the issue is solved? In that case, consider adding it as an answer so it will help future readers

Comment: My answer was deleted, not sure why.